# How to access the webcam by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I need to open the webcam via JavaScript
I know it is possible to access the html5 by `<video>` but need access webcam with pure JavaScript

Can someone help me or give me some ideas?

I need only access the webcam with JavaScript and sorry for my English, I'm using Google translator.

I can't use tag '< video >'

Comment: Did you need to access the webcam by javascript, or something else?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Support for this optional HTML5 module is [not universal](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/device-getUserMedia.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12680547/638127

Comment: see http://www.webrtc.org/ for more information.  Try it out and come back once you have something that doesn't work

Comment: @Chris Actually what I need is a webcam to identify the movement of my hand, but everything with javascript, so I need to open the webcam with javascript so I'm going in stages

Comment: I can not use the tag <video>

Comment: Here is another working sample https://github.com/saineshwar/WebCamASP.NETCORE

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As I stated as comment, I'm confused about your wording. You said, you know that "HTML5" can access the webcam, but you need it by pure Javascript.

Well, in case you don't know, *HTML5* introduced the such called *WebRTC* which is short for *Real-Time Communications*. Part of that, a new thing called <strike>navigator.getUserMedia()</strike> `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)` was introduced as well. That is, an ECMAscript object, which allows you to get access to the users machine *WebCam* and *Microphone* devices.

As you can see, the whole show is embedded in the *HTML5* rollout / spec, so we cannot really separate the Javascript from the HTML5 here.

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC
- <strike>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/navigator.getUserMedia</strike>
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Answer (score 12):

Here is a js library that uses flash only in a HTML5 fallback situation:

https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

From the code samples:

```
<script src="webcam.js"></script>

<div id="my_camera" style="width:320px; height:240px;"></div>
<div id="my_result"></div>

<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );

    function take_snapshot() {
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        } );
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(take_snapshot())">Take Snapshot</a>
```

Comment: So simple! (+1).

Comment: But it is not allowing to use camera with http in server

Comment: It gives this error "Webcam.js Error: Could not locate DOM element to attach to." Any further solution ?
@JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez

Comment: @SudhirDehade, ¿did you add the two `<div>`s "my_camera" and "my_result"?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910224/webcam-js-error-could-not-locate-dom-element-to-attach-to   Please check this link

Answer (score 4):

There's [this great tutorial from HTML5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Basically, [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/navigator.getUserMedia) lets the browsers ask for the permission and then lets you use the camera.

You must be aware that it's still badly supported and that the API might change again, especially if you want to send those streams over internet.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few javascript libraries for doing this now.

- <s>Script Cam: http://www.scriptcam.com/</s> (dead)
- jQuery Webcam: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Comment: They're not HTML5 based. Both of them need Flash.

Comment: @dystroy so? OP didn't specify that answers should only include HTML5-based solutions. He has the HTML5 tag, but the text of his question doesn't mention it as a requirement at all.

Comment: I was precising something that might not be obvious from the short answer, I wasn't saying the answer was bad. This being said, even if the question is far from clear, I read "access the **html5** by but need access webcam to **pure javascript**".