# How to integrate web camera in jsp(web Application) project

Tags: webcam, image-capture

I have to integrate web camera in gate pass system(visitor management system).
I am new to this and I am confused how to use web camera.
When any visitor comes to gate security person will take information from him and fill the information. He need to take his photo and print the gate pass.
I am confused that how to communicate to web camera because web camera is in client side not in server computer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have updated my question please check and suggest. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This post - [How to access the webcam by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417036/how-to-access-the-webcam-by-javascript) - includes some useful info on how to access webcams in JS.

Also, you can try this [online demo of webcam capture](http://www.dynamsoft.com/demo/dws/online_demo_webcam.aspx) using a 3rd party SDK and see how it meets your needs.