# Streaming external (usb3) camera footage to a video element in chrome for android

Tags: javascript, android, camera, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm developing a web application for remote assistance.
The webpage uses WebRTC to stream footage from the camera of one client to the other client.

Everything is working fine, with the default internal phone cameras that is (via navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()).
The problem is that I'm developing this for a smartglass connected to the phone via USB3. I want to use the camera from the smartglass instead of the internal camera's.

When I enumerate all devices, I only get two audio devices and two video devices (the two internal cameras) even with the smartglass plugged in. I'm logging this remotely in chrome for desktop.

Also navigator.usb.getDevices won't give me any results.

Is it possible to access USB cameras from Javascript in Chrome for android?

This is not a duplicate question. In contrast to the other question I DO have access to the camera's, only not the camera I want, which is an external camera connected to my phone by USB3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the webcam by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417036/how-to-access-the-webcam-by-javascript)

Comment: The question this is a "possible duplicate" of is rather confusing and the answers do not really help either. I've tried a few things other questions, threads and tutorials suggested before posting my own question, neither of the tried solutions did work.