# Webcam.js Error: Could not locate DOM element to attach to

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, view, webcam.js

I am trying to use Webcam.js to capture image in my MVC project. But at the initial level I have an issue `"Could not locate DOM element to attach to."`

I have attached script

```
<style>
    .Camera {
        width: 320px;
        height: 240px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/webcam.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.set({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });
     Webcam.attach('#Camera');
</script>
```

**In View**

```
 <div>
       <div id="Camera" class="Camera"> </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="takeshot" value="Capture" onClick="take_snapshot()" />
 </div>
```

What is the possible cause?

Comment: Try using another library, like `webcodecamjs.js` (in GitHub). This is the one I'm using now for a QR ticket reader system.

Answer (score 1):

place your javascript functions beneath the tag/element id:camera and id:takeshot

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Delete the class Camera, happened with me but after deleting the class and just keeping the "id" it worked.

camera = document.getElementById("camera");

Webcam.attach(camera);

Webcam.set({
width:350,
height:300,
image_format : 'png',
png_quality:90
});

Comment: Here is a quick tip : you can use code fences to highlight the codes and make it more readable